# Efficient Dijkstra's for many sources and many targets

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I'm looking for an efficient way to traverse a large graph with many source vertices and many destination vertices. Specifically, I'd like to find the shortest path for each (source, destination) pair, if such a path exists. Obviously, this could be done with a breadth-first search for every single source point, but given that many paths in the graph will be traversed multiple times, I imagine there will be a shorter way.

The following facts may be relevant:

- The graph is directed, and very sparse. It has some cycles.
- For the vast majority of (source, destination) pairs, no path will exist.
- My graph is implemented in C++, as nodes with pointers to parents and children (bidirectional traversal is possible). Edges have weights attached to them.

Comment: I strongly suspect the additional complexity of such a solution would outweigh the benefits of a brute force: repeat for each start-point, dijkstra-to-everywhere approach. But take a look at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6eaf/7951c69763bdbb27bdcb8cca596f06699007.pdf

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

OK so I basically implemented a multi-source multi-destination version of contraction hierarchies. It should be able to directly apply to Dijkstra's algorithm. Basically, for each source, you create a forward priority queue and a distance map. For each destination, you create a backward priority and a distance map. You manually create all pairs of source-destination (unsettled ones). Then while a pair is unsettled, iteratively pick a pair and does one-step forward and backward search. For each forward search, you check the just-settled vertex in the reverse direction of its unsettled destinations. Update the tentative shortest distances as appropriate. You do the same thing for the backward direction. So basically you reuse the search progress from every source and every destination. You should be able to replace Contraction Hierarchies by bi-directional Dijkstra's algorithm.